# How to retrieve the real name (Name and surname) of a Facebook profile that signed in with Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

How can I retrieve the real first name and surname of a Facebook profile that logged in using the Firebase authentication?

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
fullNameTextView.setText(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName());
userNameTextView.setText(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName());        
Picasso.get().load(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl()).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_action_profile).into(profilePictureImageView);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That information doesn't exist in the `FirebaseUser` object. To solve this, you should first get the list of providers and find the one you are interested in. So please check the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
List<? extends UserInfo> userInfoList = firebaseUser.getProviderData();
for (UserInfo userInfo : userInfoList) {
    String providerId = userInfo.getProviderId();
    if (providerId.equals(FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID)) {
        String name = userInfo.getDisplayName();
        Log.d("TAG", name);
    }
}
```

The result in the logcat will be the name of the user that has was authenticated using Facebook.

Comment: alex I don´t know if you are familiar with twitter authenfication but if you are please help me on my newest question

Comment: I'll take a look and if I'll know the answer, I'll write to you.